# Tkinter canvas hexcode color inconsistencies?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working on a project where I want to run a Python script to generate an image with many abstract colored lines, and then feed that image into a friend's program. That said, I colored those lines with certain hexcodes my friend's program will recognize and operate on, but even though I specified the values, the resulting image does not have the specific colors I need in it. Looking into this, I realized the [graphics](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) [engine](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/graphref.html) I was using is built on top of a little something called tkinter, and somehow that was ganking up the colors. Here are some examples of colors expected and recorded:

- expected >> recorded
- 255 128 0 >> 255 126 44
- 0 128 255 >> 0 130 247
- 128 255 0 >> 111 254 80

...and so on. also, here's my code if it helps:

```
from graphics import *
from random import randint

def main():

    # First I'll initialize a black window:
    win = GraphWin("Click on the screen while the small window is green", 1000,700)
    win.setBackground("black")

    # Indicator window initialization
    indicator = GraphWin("green = ready, red = drawing", 50,50)
    indicator.setBackground("green")

    # Setup initial ghost lines
    left = Line(Point(10,10), Point(10,690))
    right = Line(Point(990,10), Point(990,690))

    lines =[left,right] # this array is really important
    arr = []

    for x in range(50):
        p = win.getMouse() # click
        indicator.setBackground("red") # drawing time!
        
        # Gets the midpoint of each line drawn before the click, and
        # draws a line from each midpoint to the click.
        num = len(lines)
        for i in range(num):
            q = lines[i].getCenter()
            newline = Line(p,q)
            doodle(newline,randcolor(),win)
            lines.append(newline)
            
        indicator.setBackground("green") # click time!

def randcolor():
    r = randint(0,5)

    bright_orange = color_rgb(255,128,0) # 255 128-6 0-44 
    bright_sapphire = color_rgb(0,128,255) # 0 128-30 255-47 
    bright_lime = color_rgb(128,255,0) # 128-11 255-4 0-80
    dark_orange = color_rgb(128,64,0) # 128-30 64-3 0-16
    dark_sapphire = color_rgb(0,64,128) # 0 64-5 128-4
    dark_lime = color_rgb(64,128,0) # 64-55 128 0-35

    # reso_wires = ["#ff8000","#0080ff", "#80ff00", "#804000","#004080", "#408000"]
    reso_wires = [bright_orange, bright_sapphire, bright_lime, dark_orange, dark_sapphire, dark_lime]

    color = reso_wires[r]
    return color

def doodle(x,color,win):
    '''
    This is your one-stop drawing function. It colors the line, sends it to the
    window, and it even supports line declaration as the first parameter.  
    '''

    x.setOutline(color)
    x.setWidth(5)
    x.draw(win)

    nodepoints = [x.getP1(), x.getP2()]
    rc = Image(nodepoints[0],"xor_node.png")
    rc.draw(win)

    rd = Image(nodepoints[1],"xor_node.png")
    rd.draw(win)

main()
```

can someone help me debug this hexcode color inconsistency? I totally understand if the only way to solve this is to delve into the code of tkinter's Canvas itself and deal with x11 primitives.

Comment: EXACTLY how are you saving the image?  Remember if you use JPEG, the compression will change some of the colors.  If you're saving in CMYK (which is unlikely), that also uses a different color range.

Comment: @ Tim - screenshots taken save in .png if that helps. thanks for your comment ~ SEA

Comment: There are so many variables in onscreen drawing.  If your lines are 1 pixel wide, then you could be seeing the result of antialiasing to smooth the line edges.  You could be seeing the result of some kind of "dark mode" color matching.  When I run your app on Windows, the colors exactly match your numbers.

Comment: that could be it!!! i've been running this on mac! thanks again